# Managing AMD dependencies with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The Ember CLI documentation describes how to manage AMD dependencies [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-amd-asset). Basically, you import them like any other dependency in your Brocfile, then you export them as a second argument. To borrow from the documentation's example:

```
app.import('bower_components/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js', {
   exports: {
     'ic-ajax': [
       'default',
       'defineFixture',
       'lookupFixture',
       'raw',
       'request',
     ]
  }
});
```

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting something like this to work with my own code. Although I get no build errors, when I try to import one of my custom AMD assets, it is always returned as undefined. I haven't worked much with AMD, so perhaps my bug is coming from a faulty implementation of that code. It looks something like this:

```
define('annotators',
  ["exports"],
  function(__exports__) {

    function1 = function(var1){
      this.var1 = var1
    }

    __exports__.function1 = function1;

    function2 = function(var1){
      this.var1 = var1
    }

    __exports__.function2 = function2;
  }

)
```

Within my app, I try to import it with something like:

```
import function1 from 'annotators';
```

And in my Brocfile, I import/export it like:

```
app.import('vendor/annotators/main.js', {
   exports: {
     'annotators': [
       'function1',
       'function2'
     ]
  }
});
```

What might be going on here?

Comment: It is not really clear on what exactly to do as I'm having the same problems and there doesn't seem to be any new information or documentation on the web. Have you resolved your problem ?